# Passing Intent data from Activity to Class

Tags: android, string

I want to pass string from my activity class to my class that is not extended to activity. I know this is possible but how to do that? I am new to android development so please help

Comment: Can you share some of your current code please? Do you create a new object ob the class or does it already exist?

Comment: Show your work .

Comment: [parameterized constructor](https://www.javatpoint.com/constructor)

Comment: If it's just a class, create a static property and set it's value.

Comment: How did you know "I know this is possible but how to do that"?

Comment: I read many documentations on internet and they provided some solutions too but nothing worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In android you can send data through Intent or Intent followed by Bundle like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(current_activity.this, linked_class.class);
i.putextra("Key", value);
```

And get the value(suppose string value) in another class like:

```
String value = getIntent.getExtra("String key which you used when send value");
```

**Option 2**:

```
class yourClass {
public static String _utfValue = "";
void sendValue(){
   _utfValue  = "some value";
}
}
```

And fetch this value in your java class like:

```
String value = A._utfValue ;
```

**Option 3**: You can use SharedPreference to save the value and get it from other class.

**Option 4**: You can use a static method with some return value and fetch the method in your java class through class name.

All the options are rough here. So just check this ,hope one of these will help you .

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: Thankyou so much :))

Answer (score -1):

You create static variable and access anotherclass

like

```
Static String mydemo=null;
mydemo="sagar";
```

then access directly in another class